# CCXT - Assigning leverage (python)

Tags: python, ccxt

I seem to be having a hard time passing values into my futures trade using CCXT and python.

Right now I have the code to open my position, SL and TP's as follows:

```
def open_trade(symbol, entry, leverage, take_profit, stop_loss, position_type, size):
    # Load the time difference
    exchange.load_time_difference()
    
    # Assuming you already have 'exchange' defined somewhere
    ticker = exchange.fetch_ticker(symbol)
    current_price = ticker['last']

    if position_type == 'LONG' and not (entry[1] < current_price < entry[0]):
        print(f"Current price ({current_price}) is not between entry1 ({entry[1]}) and entry2 ({entry[0]}). Signal NOT executed")
        return None
    elif position_type == 'SHORT' and not (entry[0] < current_price < entry[1]):
        print(f"Current price ({current_price}) is not between entry1 ({entry[0]}) and entry2 ({entry[1]}). Signal NOT executed")
        return None

    # Define additional parameters, including leverage
    additional_params = {
        'leverage': calc_leverage(symbol, leverage),
    }

    # Set leverage
    exchange.fapiPrivate_post_leverage({
    "symbol": symbol,
    "leverage": leverage,
})

    # Determine the position side based on the order type
    if position_type == 'LONG':
        additional_params['positionSide'] = 'LONG'
    elif position_type == 'SHORT':
        additional_params['positionSide'] = 'SHORT'
    else:
        print(f"Invalid position_type: {position_type}")
        return None

    # Place market order with additional parameters
    order = exchange.create_order(
        symbol=symbol,
        type='market',
        side='buy' if position_type == 'LONG' else 'sell',
        amount=size,
        params=additional_params,
    )
    position_info = order
    print("Futures position information:")
    print(str(position_info) + "\n")

    # Add stopPrice to additional_params
    additional_params['stopPrice'] = stop_loss
    

    # Place stop loss order
    stop_loss_order = exchange.create_order(
        symbol=symbol,
        type='STOP_MARKET',
        side='sell' if position_type == 'LONG' else 'buy',
        amount=size,
        price=stop_loss,  # This is the stop loss price
        params=additional_params,
    )

    position_info = stop_loss_order
    print("Stop Loss information:")
    print(str(position_info) + "\n")

    size = size/5  # Split the size into 5 take profit orders
    i = 1
    for tp in take_profit:
        # Add stopPrice to additional_params
        additional_params['stopPrice'] = tp
        # Place take profit order
        take_profit_order = exchange.create_order(
            symbol=symbol,
            type='TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET',
            side='sell' if position_type == 'LONG' else 'buy',
            amount=size,
            price=tp,  # This is the take profit price
            params=additional_params,
        )

        position_info = take_profit_order
        print('Take Profit: ' + str(i) + ' information:')
        print(str(position_info) + "\n")
        i += 1
```

Initially I had thought that this worked:

```
# Define additional parameters, including leverage
    additional_params = {
        'leverage': calc_leverage(symbol, leverage),
    }
```

but after testing n a different signal it became clear that it did not do anything... I then went to find this post: [Leverage not taken into account by Binance with CCXT in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71910014/leverage-not-taken-into-account-by-binance-with-ccxt-in-python)

but even the code provided here doesnt seem to do the trick:

```
markets = exchange.load_markets()
market = exchange.market(symbol)  

exchange.fapiPrivate_post_leverage({  
    'symbol': 'symbol',
    'leverage': leverage,
})
```

and keeps returning an error with the symbol, regardless of trying  `BTCUSDT`, `BTC/USDT`, or `BTC/USDT:USDT` when using

```
ccxt.binanceusdm
```

or

```
AttributeError: 'binance' object has no attribute 'fapiPrivate_post_leverage'
```

when using

```
ccxt.binance
```

This was found after some other post that I saw suggested using

```
exchange = ccxt.binanceusdm({
    'apiKey': 'blabla',
    'secret': 'secret',
    'enableRateLimit': True,
    'options': {
        'defaultType': 'future'
    }
})
```

instead of

```
exchange = ccxt.binance({...
```

This issue is not limited to the leverage but even directly assigning a SL or TP on a trade, thus my code has 3 iterations of

```
order
```

any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation there is

```
binance.setLeverage (leverage, symbol[, params])
```

I somehow missed than and the code works as expected now